# In OpenERP, What is the difference between "send a message" and "log a note"?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

In OpenERP, What is the difference between "`send a message`" and "`log a note`".

I found two option "send a message" and "log a note" in form view under Leads, Quotations, Sales Orders, etc., You'll find it.

What is the difference between them and what all are the uses of those options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Send a message`

- "Send a message to all followers of the document".
- It create a log as well as send messages to all followers, those who are following the document.

`Log a note`

- "Log a note for this document. No notification will be sent"
- It doesn't send any notification/mail to any of the followers.

Answer (score 4):

1. **"Send a message"** - Sends an email to the related follower, and the follower can view that message in their OpenERP inbox menu.
2. **"Log a note"** - Just logs a note, and does not send a message to the followers.

Answer (score 1):

**Send a message** Author can able to send the message to recipients as a follower of that record which will be notified to  follower in odoo inbox, also we can check in Technical --> Messages . It is used generally to alert the follower when something needs to be tracked by them.

**Log a Note** Follower will not be notified, but visible in the form it is generally used when some adjustment is done which need to be monitor if anything goes wrong or the author use this TODO purpose,the log will be highlighted with darker grey colour but message will not be like that